# как вывести значение связанных таблиц mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте, у меня есть бд mysql в ней есть таблица users, services и clientlist. таблица clientlist связанна с users и services, в ней хранятся ID - users и services. Как мне сделать, запросе PHP, что бы он вернул мне не просто ID таблиц users, services, а вывел полное их содержание. или как мне оптимизировать БД. Если делать внешние ключи на всех полях в  users и services то придётся в таблице clientlist создавать дополнительные поля, плюс когда пытаюсь связать второй внешний ключ Mysql выдаёт непонятную ошибку.
Скриншот БД:

clientlist:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

user:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

services [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ваш код запроса и ошибку добавьте

Comment: ничего не понятно. зачем создавать внешние ключи на всех колонках, на что они должны указывать. внешние ключи используются только что бы указать что в данном поле могут встречаться только такие же значения как значения первичного ключа другой таблицы. И это единственное их назначение

Answer (score 1):

Объединение таблиц с помощью [JOIN](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/JOIN.html)

Что-то вроде этого

```
SELECT * FROM clientlist c
  INNER JOIN users u ON c.client = u.ID
  INNER JOIN services s ON c.services = s.id
```

Пару слов
В таблице `clientlist` колонки которые указывают на другие таблици пишите, вроде `users_id`
В таблице `users` у вас `ID` с большими буквами, хотя везде маленькие, не есть хорошо, можно ошибиться

Comment: с каких пор sql стал регистрозависимым, чтобы ошибаться?

Comment: Спасибо вам большое, за помощь))))) очень сильно вам благодарен

Comment: @teran в php: что-то вроде этого, $a = ['id' => 15, 'ID' => 'st'];var_dump($a); а потом сиди и думай, что не так))))